# How to implement token based authentication in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, access-token

I have the username and password and an API for token, I want to implement the token based authentication using local-storage. I am confused where to start any useful link would be helpful.

Comment: This might help you https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/token-based-authentication-with-angularjs-nodejs--cms-22543

Answer (score 0):

@ahmer what backend are you using, I recently created a token based authentication using angular and python flask, the library is called [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer), check out satellizer compatibility with the backend you use

Comment: I am using asp.net for back-end but I need to implement on the front end for now, back-end is working fine now I have checked with postman.

Comment: @AhmerKhan ok this one supports asp.net backend. great